# VB Macros in two worksheets that compare 4 fields and then paste a value

Tags: vba

I am new to VB so any help you can provide would be great.  I have two worksheets.   They have four fields in common between the two sheets.  The rows will have many more fields that will not match.   if the four fields match then I need to paste two fields into the second sheet.

Although this works it is hardcoded and I have to do this for each line.

I would like to create a double loop and allow the four fields on the row to compare to the second sheet to each row to see if there is a match.  if so it will paste the two fields other wise it will go on to the next row in the first sheet and do the process again.

```
If [w2.Range.("b2")] = [w1.Range.("g3")] Then
  If [w2.Range.("c2")] = [w1.Range.("b3")] Then
   If [w2.Range.("d2")] = [w1.Range.("c3")] Then
     w1.Select
     Range("N3:O3").Select
     Selection.Copy
     w2.Select
     Range("G2:H2").Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
 End If
 End If
 End If
```

Any help would be great.

I got the two sheets worked and basically the comparison.   the only issue I have now is how the loops and incrementing  and not going down to the next row.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Set w1 = Worksheets("DDR_Mar'17")
Set w2 = Worksheets("Release DrillDown")
Dim drea As String
Dim seva As String

SelRow = Selection.Row

'category ITSR on "DDR_Mar'17" sheet
   itsra = w1.Cells(SelRow, 7)
'category Application on "DDR Mar'17" sheet
   appa = w1.Cells(SelRow, 2)
'category SubCategory on "DDR Mar'17" sheet
   scata = w1.Cells(SelRow, 3)
'category DRE on "DDR Mar'17" sheet
   drea = w1.Cells(SelRow, 14)
'category SEV on "DDR Mar'17" sheet
   seva = w1.Cells(SelRow, 15)


lr = w1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

SelRow = Selection.Row
'category ITSR on "Release Drilldown" sheet
   itsrb = w2.Cells(SelRow, 2)
'category Application on "Release Drilldown" sheet
   appb = w2.Cells(SelRow, 3)
'category SubCategory on "Release Drilldown" sheet
   scatb = w2.Cells(SelRow, 4)
'category DRE on "Release Drilldown" sheet
   dreb = w2.Cells(SelRow, 7)
'category SEV on "Release Drilldown" sheet
 '  sevb = w2.Cells(SelRow, 8)

lr2 = w2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


For x = 1 To lr2
   w2.Cells(x, 1) = x
 For y = 1 To lr
   w1.Cells(y, 1) = y

  If itsra = itsrb Then
    If appa = appb Then
     If scata = scatb Then
          w = w + 1
  End If
  End If
  End If

Next y
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is not so clear, please edit and try to make it more clear. There is no such definition in Excel as Field i guess you mean Cell by this. You also say you want to control four fields if they match or not, but in your code you are checking only 3 fields also you should correct that. Finally you can simply make copy paste operation like `w1.Range("N3:O3").Copy Destination:=w2.Range("G2:H2")`

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each row testing the values with a for loop

```
Dim trange As Range
Set trange = w2.Range("B2:D4") 'Range you're testing
For Each trow In trange.Rows
    If trow.Columns(1) = w1.Range("G3") _
    And trow.Columns(2) = w1.Range("B3") _
    And trow.Columns(3) = w1.Range("C3") Then
        w1.Range("N3:O3").Copy Destination:=trow.Offset(0, 5)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

If you're looking to loop through w1 as well, you can set up a second range and nest the for eaches

```
For each trow In trange.rows
     For each rrow in rrange.rows
         if trow.column(1) = rrow.column(1) And ect....
```

Comment: Thanks I got the two sheet thing worked out.   Only thing I am having a issue is incrementing the next row to check the critera.

Answer (score 0):

I think Select method is not gooo.

```
If [w2.Range.("b2")] = [w1.Range.("g3")] Then
  If [w2.Range.("c2")] = [w1.Range.("b3")] Then
        If [w2.Range.("d2")] = [w1.Range.("c3")] Then
            w2.Range("G2:H2").Value = w1.Range("N3:O3").Value
        End If
    End If
 End If
```